# List of Entire Torah

Tags: torah-study, tzaddikim

It used be a thing that every year, Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky zt"l - finished the entire Torah.

Is there a list of all Seforim he used to learn?

Comment: I have answered this [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/102093/11501)

Comment: yes! thank you so much!!!